# Android:Getting ArrayList values to other class

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a problem in getting arraylist values.
I have a method in azan.java class which computes prayer Timings and stores it in an arrayList like this.

```
 ArrayList prayerTimes = prayers.getPrayerTimes(cal, latitude,
                longitude, timezone);
```

and I want to match these timings with system time after one minute repeatedly,thats why I created an `aysncTask` class , but I am unable to get the values of those prayerTimes in `asyncTask` class, I am using this approach

```
if(systemTime.equals(azan.prayerTimes.get(0))){
    player.start;
}else if (systemTime.equals(azan.prayerTimes.get(1))){
   player2.start;
}
```

When I debug this , `azan.prayerTimes.get(0)))` array stores nothing. It shows size 0 and values also 0 ,and I got threadpool executer error..
Can anyone help me

Comment: Salam, can you please post whole code?

Answer (score 0):

Declare `ArrayList prayerTimes` as a global variable.

```
Class Ajan{
   ArrayList prayerTimes;
   yourMethod(){
        prayerTimes = prayers.getPrayerTimes(cal, latitude,
                longitude, timezone);
   }

   Class YourAsyncTask {
   }
}
```

Comment: I have declared it..But prayerTimes array also get values only when getTime method is called..when it is called prayerTimes size got 5 and values also but when try to access them in other class it shows size 0 and values 0

Comment: @NoorAfshan Is your AsyncTash inside the main class where you are assigning the ArrayList variable ?

Comment: ammm No , I have created an Inner class under Azan.java

Comment: @NoorAfshan Then declare the variable  like as shown in my answer, it should work

Comment: @NoorAfshan Please accept the answer to help future visitors :)

Answer (score 0):

try adding these methods, in **Azan.java** class:

```
class Azan {
   ArrayList prayerTimes = new ArrayList();

   // assign method variables as yours.
   public void setPrayerTimes(Object cal, int latitude, int longitude, String timezon) {
      prayerTimes = prayers.getPrayerTimes(cal, latitude, longitude, timezone);
   }

   public ArrayList getPrayerTimes() {
      return prayerTimes;
   }
}
```

Comment: @Awais ..thanks but I fixed my problem before your comment..:)

Comment: @NoorAfshan, nice to hear that it was fixed. :)